# Extract the occurrence of textual amount separately using C# regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have some paragraphs that contained the Textual Amounts multiple times 
(e.g : Insurance
with limits of not less than **Five Hundred Thousand Dollars** per person and **One
Million Dollars**) per occurrence insuring against all liability)

I have the following code that is responsible for extracting the numbers from the textual amount. Like (one thousand five hundred = 1500). It works fine if amount occurrence is only one but difficult when there is more than one occurrence of the amount in textual format. The numbers returned are not correct.

```
 private static Dictionary<string, long> numberTable = new Dictionary<string, long>
        { {"zero",0},{"one",1},{"two",2},{"three",3},{"four",4},
        {"five",5},{"six",6},{"seven",7},{"eight",8},{"nine",9},
        {"ten",10},{"eleven",11},{"twelve",12},{"thirteen",13},
        {"fourteen",14},{"fifteen",15},{"sixteen",16},
        {"seventeen",17},{"eighteen",18},{"nineteen",19},{"twenty",20},
        {"thirty",30},{"forty",40},{"fifty",50},{"sixty",60},
        {"seventy",70},{"eighty",80},{"ninety",90},{"hundred",100},
        {"thousand",1000},{"million",1000000},{"billion",1000000000},
        {"trillion",1000000000000},{"quadrillion",1000000000000000},
        {"quintillion",1000000000000000000}};


var numbers = Regex.Matches(numberString, @"\w+").Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value.ToLowerInvariant())
                .Where(v => numberTable.ContainsKey(v)).Select(v => numberTable[v]);
            long acc = 0, total = 0L;
            foreach (var n in numbers)
            {
                if (n >= 1000)
                {
                    total += (acc * n);
                    acc = 0;
                }
                else if (n >= 100)
                {
                    acc *= n;
                }
                else acc += n;
            }
            string a = Convert.ToString((total + acc) * (numberString.StartsWith("minus", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? -1 : 1));
            return a;
```

Can anyone help or give suggestion to solve the issue.

If I input only the text ="Insurance with limits of not less than **Five Hundred Thousand** Dollars" then the output is correct that us 500,000

But If i input the text = "Insurance
with limits of not less than **Five Hundred Thousand Dollars** per person and **One
Million Dollars**) per occurrence insuring against all liability"

Then answer I get is 1500000 , But I need this separately like 50,000 and 1000,000

Note: I also have in my mind that if I can get all amounts to end up with dollars and convert them one by one. But I don't think that will be a good choice,
I open for any kind of discussion. 
thanks

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with multiple sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs. It would be particularly helped if the [mcve] was a console app.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278081/convert-words-string-to-int) link seems to have same answer as asked in question

Comment: yes code is same @Lucifer , but My question is different I edited the question please take a look again

Comment: @mjwills see my answer and please suggest and improvements, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to below code :

> Below we check that if the digit is continuation of the number (i.e 5 100 1000 dollars) the we add(In Context Multiply) them into same element which is present in list(`sample`) else we add the data into new Element of the list and repeat the process

Example :- 
Consider this -> If we remove all place from  *Five Hundred Thousand Dollars* we will get *FiveHundredThousandDollars* Here we can see that the difference between `e` of `five` and `h` of `Hundred` is exactly 1 so we can conclude that number is same.

```
    public static List<long> ToLong(string numberString)
    {
        var numbers = Regex.Matches(numberString, @"\w+").Cast<Match>()
             .Select(m => m.Value.ToLowerInvariant())
             .Where(v => numberTable.ContainsKey(v))
             .Select(v => numberTable[v]);

        long acc = 0, total = 0L;
        List<long> sample = new List<long>();
        int prevIndex = 0, currIndex = 0;
        string currKey = "", prevKey = "";
        int i = 0;
        List<long> revList = numbers.ToList();
        revList.Reverse();
        foreach (var n in numbers)
        {
            numberString = numberString.Replace(" ", "");
            currKey = numberTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.ToString().ToLower() == n.ToString().ToLower()).Key;
            currIndex = numberString.ToLower().IndexOf(currKey.ToLower());
            bool isDiffNuber = !(prevIndex == 0 || currIndex - (prevIndex + prevKey.Length - 1) == 1);


            if (!isDiffNuber)
            {
                if (n >= 1000)
                {
                    total += (acc * n);
                    acc = 0;
                }
                else if (n >= 100)
                {
                    acc *= n;
                }
                else
                    acc += n;
            }

            if (isDiffNuber || numbers.Last() == n)
            {
                long val = total + acc;
                sample.Add(val);

                i++;
                prevIndex = 0;
                currIndex = 0;
                prevKey = "";
                currKey = "";
                total = 0;
                acc = 1;
            }


            prevIndex = currIndex;
            prevKey = currKey;
        }

        return sample;
    }
```

Note:- This solution will only work for above given sample if user adds `Five Hundred "and" .......` then current sample will fail to do so.

[image]

Comment: @JotSingh happy to help

Comment: Sorry Its Ajax not Regex

Comment: Three Hundred Twenty Eight Thousand , Can you please check the code with this string ?? It is returning 300 , 160000 , but It have to return 3280000

Comment: Lucifer still no luck , just try testing with : e.g : Insurance with limits of not less than Five Hundred Thousand Dollars per person and One Million Dollars
It is giving 500 000 and 1500000 , meanz adding the 500 000 with one million dollar for last text we found

Comment: Now code started behaving like my first code, I mean adding the previous values

Comment: you should've mentioned all of this previously while asking the question, see edit

Comment: see Now I have helped you with three issues you have posted I cant at your desk and do your code for you now you have figure out the problem urself this is the max I can help