# I am confused how Convert.ToInt32() works?

Tags: c#

I just started the CodeCademy C# course this evening and have a question. I am in the converting data type section and was able to "pass" the exercise but the code did not output what I expected. When I run the program it prompts "Whats your favorite number?" if I input 5 it does what I expected and outputs "your favorite number is 5". What I don't understand is if I input `five`, the program throws an `incorrect format error`. I thought the Convert.ToInt32() method was supposed to take a string input and convert it to its corresponding integer? Any help understanding what I am doing or thinking wrong is appreciated.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

   // Ask user for fave number
   Console.Write("Enter your favorite number?: ");

   // Turn that answer into an integer

  int faveNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine("your favorite number is:" + faveNumber);

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Convert.ToInt32()` takes a string that only contains numeric characters. Anything else is an error. Converting english-language words (such as `"five"`) into a numeric value isn't what `Convert.ToInt32()` does.

If you want to convert strings such as `"one hundred and fifteen"` into an `int`, it's a little more complicated. Here's an answer I wrote for fun a while ago that does just this (albeit to `long` rather than `int`):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278412/14357

Answer (score 1):

Convert.ToInt32() only able to convert digit character. It can't recognize english vocab. If you want to recognize the english language, you can write the similar function to do the work.

```
   private static int ConvertToNumber(string input)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case "Five":
                return 5;
                // do the remaining work

            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. What if I want "two billion one hundred and forty-seven million, four hundred and eighty-three thousand, six hundred and forty-seven"? Should I have two billion cases? What about where the user just inputs "2147483647"?

Comment: Yes of course it is not a good solution for "two billion one hundred and forty-seven million, four hundred and eighty-three thousand, six hundred and forty-seven". Just provide the idea based on the use case. You may refer to spender answer for your question.