# How do I make two=2 equivalent in python?

Tags: python, numbers, equivalent

I'm working with python to make a trivia game.  Some of my answers are numbers.  I'm using the .lower() to make it so that Two or tWO would work, but how would I get 2 to be equivalent in python so that two or 2 would answer the question?  I know that C++ has a way to make the two types equivalent, but I'm not sure how to do that with python.

Comment: What way does C++ have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to Convert Number words to Integers? Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about this:

```
answer = raw_input("Your answer: ")
if answer.lower() in ("2", "two"):
    # Answer was good.
```

This method takes the answer, makes it lowercase, and then sees if it can be found in the tuple `("2", "two")`.  It will return `True` for input such as:

```
"Two"
"two"
"2"
"tWo"
```

etc.  Anything else will have it return `False`.