# Looking for algorithm to parse medication notes from EHR

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to use python and nltk to parse some doctor notes that describe a medication prescription. I'm looking for a method to identify a numerical value for # items taken and how often the items are taken.

```
1 TABLET DAILY
TAKE 1 TABLET DAILY
ONE TABLET TWICE DAILY
2 DAILY
TWO TABLETS DAILY
ONE PILL AT BEDTIME
1/2 PILL TWICE DAILY
ROLLING WALKER WITH SEAT ATTACHMENT AND HAND BRAKES
ONE PILL DAILY
1 TAB PO DAILY
ONE PILL TWICE A DAY WITH MEALS AS NEEDED
1 TABLET TWICE DAILY
300 MG BID
ONE DAILY
1 TABLET 3 TIMES DAILY AS NEEDED
1 DAILY
TAKE 1 CAPSULE BY MOUTH 4 (FOUR) TIMES A DAY.
1 TABLET EVERY 4 TO 6 HOURS AS NEEDED
1 TABLET BY MOUTH TWICE DAILY
INJECT 34 U TWICE A DAY
```

Any advice?

Comment: This might help you along the right path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337410/nltk-reading-in-word-numbers-to-float-numbers

Comment: You could also look at this project, I couldn't get the Earley parser python code to run but the authors seem to have been working on the same problem. http://www.mit.edu/~6.863/spring2009/projects/project16.html

Answer (score 1):

Typically there are [multiple variations](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/i2b2-Medication-Extraction-Challenge-Uzuner-Solti/2e2fb45a22796edd6b267fb84908f2f584ef85eb) in which these are written by doctors in clinical notes. 
For eg:

```
1 TABLET DAILY
```

could also be written as

```
1 tab qid
```

If you are looking for a quick fix writing a python script with regular expression might help. But if you want something more long term, you could take a look at data and submissions for the [i2b2 Medication Information Extraction Challenge](https://academic.oup.com/jamia/article/17/5/514/2909108/Extracting-medication-information-from-clinical)