# number to word & word to number support with full text search

Tags: postgresql, search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

What kind of approaches are available or advisable for handling number to word matches or the reverse, word to number matches?

E.g. query: "600" should match "six hundred" and conversely a query of "six hundred" should match "600".

I can think of [manual ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers) to create lexemes for normalized forms of each representation and store that on an indexed field, so I'm not so interested in hearing about that, rather I'm curious:

1. How are others are solving this problem generally, perhaps manually like I just mentioned?
2. Are there default postgres search features to help/support this?  If not, perhaps there are for elasticsearch?
3. Other relevant feedback my question doesn't encapsulate but is important to this topic for myself and other readers to consider.

Comment: Are you only considering English for this feature?

Comment: For the sake of keeping things simple, let's say yes.