# How to convert numeric words into numeric in python

Tags: python, nlp, fuzzy

I want to convert numeric which represented in words into numbers.

for example,
  `thirty four thousand four fifty` into its corresponding numerical value  `34450`. 
Also have some fuzzy conversions like `"Please pay thirty-four thousand four fifty dollars"` then the output to be `34450`.

Comment: Here's a silly implementation: http://pastebin.com/WwFCjYtt =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For numbers to words, try "num2words" package:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words

For words to num, I tweaked the code slightly from the code here:
[Is there a way to convert number words to Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers)

```
from num2words import num2words

def text2int(textnum, numwords={}):
    if not numwords:
      units = [
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight",
        "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen",
        "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen",
      ]

      tens = ["", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]

      scales = ["hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion"]

      numwords["and"] = (1, 0)
      for idx, word in enumerate(units):    numwords[word] = (1, idx)
      for idx, word in enumerate(tens):     numwords[word] = (1, idx * 10)
      for idx, word in enumerate(scales):   numwords[word] = (10 ** (idx * 3 or 2), 0)

    current = result = 0
    for word in textnum.split():
        if word not in numwords:
          raise Exception("Illegal word: " + word)

        scale, increment = numwords[word]
        current = current * scale + increment
        if scale > 100:
            result += current
            current = 0

    return result + current

#### My update to incorporate decimals
num = 5000222223.28
fullText = num2words(num).replace('-',' ').replace(',',' ')
print fullText

decimalSplit = fullText.split('point ')

if len(decimalSplit) > 1:
    decimalSplit2 = decimalSplit[1].split(' ')
    decPart = sum([float(text2int(decimalSplit2[x]))/(10)**(x+1) for x in range(len(decimalSplit2))])
else:
    decPart = 0

intPart = float(text2int(decimalSplit[0]))

Value = intPart + decPart

print Value
```

-> five billion  two hundred and twenty two thousand  two hundred and twenty three point two eight

-> 5000222223.28

Comment: i asked for word to number , not number to words

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: i dont think it will be able to convert decimal points @Oxymoron88

Comment: Can you give an example of how the words will look with decimal points? if it's like "eleven point sixty three", you will just have to split the string with point, do separate word to num and join them together in numeric with decimal places.

Comment: its never said as eleven point sixty three , instead it would be like eleven point six three, how would the senario be then

Comment: updated the answer - please see if this serves your purpose