# Converting non-digit strings in Python

Tags: python, parsing, nlp

What is the best way to parse non-digit strings e.g. "twenty two"->22 to integer or double values in python ? Especially what is the best way to detect that region if there are additional words in a sentence.

Thanks

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/semantic/

Comment: @PM2Ring num2words appears to only support the opposite conversion

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/akshaynagpal/w2n this has pip install

Original Comment here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34569447