# how to convert a string consisting of number in words to string of numbers in integer format in python

Tags: python, string

I have a `string` which has numbers in words format(with a string prefix). I want to convert it to string with numbers in integer format(string prefix remains as it is ). Here are some sample data of string:

```
"m.l. one two three four"
"k.f two seven six eight"
"g.h three nine zero four"
```

What I want each of them to converted to:

```
"ML1234"
"KF2768"
"GH3904"
```

I looked around on SO but couldn't find a relevant question(most of the SO questions were related to converting tens,hundreds,thousands to integers).

How can I convert this?

Comment: Check this out: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/words2num

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers

Comment: @perigon I had looked up at the SO post you mentioned but it is converting string like "seven billion three thousand..." into numbers. My requirement is to take individual words and convert it to number. So `m.l. two seven six eight` becomes `ML2768`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
string = "m.l. one two three four"

text_dict = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':4, 'five':5, 'six': 6, 'seven':7, 'eight':8, 'nine':9, 'zero':0}
split = string.split()
numerized = [str(text_dict[word]) for word in split[1:]]
prefix = split[0].upper().replace(".","")
print ("".join([prefix] + numerized))
```

Output:

```
ML1234
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

text = "m.l. one two three four"

rep = [(" zero", "0"), (" one", "1"), (" two", "2"), (" three", "3"),
       (" four", "4"), (" five", "5"), (" six", "6"), (" seven", "7"),
       (" eight", "8"), (" nine", "9"), (".", "")]
t = reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), rep, text.lower()).upper()
print(t)
```

Outputs:

```
ML1234
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = "m.l. one two three four"
numbers = {
    "one":1,
    "two":2,
    "three":3,
    "four":4,
    "five":5,
    "six":6,
    "seven":7,
    "eight":8,
    "nine":9,
    "zero":0
}
def num_map(str):
    return numbers[str]
data = data.split()
# data[0] will be having chars, rest are numbers

tmp =  ''.join(data[0].split('.')[:-1])
tmp += ''.join(map(str,map(num_map, data[1:])))
print tmp.upper()
```

map string to int and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You have so many options to choose, apart from that you have to use `reduce` function or a small library called [`words2num`](https://github.com/JDongian/words2num).

If you are using python 2.x you can include directly `reduce`, or if you are using python 3.x use `functools.reduce`.

From umutto's answer: Python 2.x

```
text = "m.l. one two three four"

rep = [(" zero", "0"), (" one", "1"), (" two", "2"), (" three", "3"),
   (" four", "4"), (" five", "5"), (" six", "6"), (" seven", "7"),
   (" eight", "8"), (" nine", "9"), (".", "")]
t = reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), rep, text.lower()).upper()
print t
```

Output

> ML1234

This is enough. If you want to use a library `words2num` is a good option

1, Install [`words2num`](https://github.com/JDongian/words2num)

```
pip install words2num
```

2, Import 'words2num'

```
from words2num import w2n
```

3, Create code with `w2n()` function

```
string = "m.l. one two three four"

word_str = string.split(" ")
result = ""

for i in word_str:
    try:
            result += str(w2n(i))
    except:
            words = i.upper().split(".")
            result += "".join(words)
print result
```

Output

> ML1234

Comment: reduce and functools.reduce are the same thing. Its just moved under functools library in [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html).

Comment: I am sorry about that I just use only 2.x. well thank you for that information.