# How can we use 'or' with '*' in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Looking at the first answer in the link:
[convert number words to Integers Python Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers)

The author uses

```
for idx, word in enumerate(scales):
   numwords[word] = (10 ** (idx * 3 or 2), 0)
```

How has the author used 'or' with multiply (*) here:

```
10 ** (idx * 3 or 2)
```

Comment: `X or Y` means `if X then X, otherwise Y`. So if `idx*3` is zero, `idx*3 or 2` is 2. Otherwise, it's `idx*3`.

Comment: @khelwood there is definitely a duplicate which explains this all in detail

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Then by all means find it.

Comment: wouldn't you want to put this into parentheses to make it more obvious? Or will `((idx*3) or 2)` not work?

Comment: @khelwood
Hi! how did you figure out that the condition to be compared against is 0? Where does it say that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante)

Comment: @patrick I think it would be the same with or without parenthesis. cause its multiply that we are using

Comment: @TejitPabari `or` tests the truthiness of the left argument. In the case of numbers, `0` is falsey and all other numbers are truthy.

Comment: @TejitPabari In Python, `0` is falsey, and all other numbers are truthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression `10 ** (idx * 3 or 2)`, if the value *idx* is zéro, then `0 * 3 = 0`.

In Python, all values like `0`, `0.0`, `""`, `[]`, `()`, `{}`, `False`, `None` are evaluated to False. See the official documentation: [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

So the equation `idx * 3 or 2` is equivalent to `False or 2` if *ixd* is 0. The result is 2.

If *idx* is not 0, the result is `idx * 3`, the *or* operator is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the positioning of idx.

For example:
if we omit "or 2" in the code and idx = 0, then...

10 ** (0 * 3) will give us 1 instead of the correct answer.

A better example:

Lets say the number is "one hundred". The position of idx for "hundred" in scales is 0. So without "or 2" in the code, "hundred" would be equal to...
10 ** (0 * 3) = 1 which isn't logically true, so you have to square 10 (hence where "or 2" comes into play) making the correction...
10 ** (2) = 100.