# Changing text to number in python

Tags: python, dataframe, text, numeric

I have a dataframe with a column called Age, which I am trying to convert to numeric. One of the values in the column is text "seven". How do I get this done using Python, so that the text gets converted to number 7? Am looking at an option where I don't need to loop through each row and convert on a case basis. Please help

Comment: Did see similar questions. but all of those read row by row through a for loop. Is there a way to check for presence of strings without looping through and get them converted?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to hardcode a list containing ['zero', 'one', 'two'] up to highest age.
Then you can get the index based on the number from the database.

```
 >>>number = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven']
 >>>index = number.index('seven')
 >>>print(index)
 7
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers) example.