# Pepper - Number recognition

Tags: pepper

I'd like to use Pepper as a calculator...
Now the first problem is the number recognition...
Considering that "*" does not work, and that it is not possible to add all numbers as concept....It is a problem.
I can write a concept composition to make recognize numbers in letters (not in numbers), e.g. "one hundred twenty one" instead of 121. Now I don't know how to convert the letters-number to digit-number in a simple way... (the only way I know is using a parser in a remote phyton function)
Another problem is that I cannot make a "sum" in qiChat language.
Is there a way to make a sum in qichat without using a %script?
If I use a script I cannot assign the result to a qichat variable, the only way is using events...
Thanks if you can suggest some simpler way to proceed.
Debora

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the 100s, the numbers are expressed in a systematic way, like in "three million two hundreds fifty two thousands six hundreds and ninety one" for "3,252,691".

As you can see, you don't need neither to capture `*` nor "*all numbers*", but rather a combination of just some possible chunks.

```
concept:(digits) ["one", "two", ...]
concept:(tens) ["ten", "twenty", ...]
concept:(number_tens) {~tens} {~digits}
concept:(number_hundreds) {~digit hundred{s}} ~number_tens
concept:(number) {~number_hundreds million{s}} {~number_hundreds thousand{s}} ~number_hundreds
u:(_~number}
    $number_out=$1
```

An `ALMemory` event named `number_out` should be raised with the value when a number is matched. You can [subscribe to it](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/dev/cpp/tutos/port_naoqi2.html#subscribing-to-an-event-from-almemory), and process it with a script to convert the natural language into numbers, like propose [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers) for example.

Comment: I've already did it, but I got  "twenty" and not 20. In this case the numbers are expressed in letters and not in numbers. So I cannot use them to make the calculator. I was trying to associating a value to each number, but for complex number I would need a script and it is not possibile to associate a script in the concepts.. Suggestions?

Comment: $number_out is an ALMemory event that any program can subscribe to, and parse it. I think I'll add that to this reply.