# Speech-to-text number capture

Tags: speech-to-text, cmusphinx

Is there a method for capturing spoken numbers via using cmusphinx?

Poking around in the cmudict-en-us.dict file I find the following,

```
forty F AO R T IY
forty-five F AO R T IY F AY V
fifty F IH F T IY
eighty EY T IY
```

Rather than having Sphinx respond with "forty, forty-five, fifty, eighty" is it possible to create a dictionary like,

```
40 F AO R T IY
45 F AO R T IY F AY V
50 F IH F T IY
80 EY T IY
```

so than arabic numerals are returned...ie 40,45,50,80? Is there such a dictionary already? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a dictionary like this, but not really recommended. You'd better recognize numbers as words and then create post-processing code to turn them into actual numbers. The reason is that user can spell the number in various ways like this:

- eight seven
- eighty seven
- a hundred and thirty five
- one three five
- one thirty [big pause] five

There are too many variants to handle them in recognizer. Once you recognized the string you can use something like [Duckling](https://github.com/facebook/duckling) to convert it to action. If Duckling is too complex for you, you can use simple regexes or python code like here [Is there a way to convert number words to Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers)