# is there an function in python can convert text to numeric?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dataset

I have a  csv data set want to convert the text to numeric , are their any function can used or using excel function ?
I tried to convert the data frame using
`pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce'.isnull())` and that not work also a tried to use `data['MainCategory'] = data['MainCategory'].astype(float)`

Comment: what kind of text? like '2' or 'two'?

Comment: @YusufBaktir  "tow"

Comment: In this platform it is appreciated if you frame your question to be informative enough, as well as show our efforts towards solving it i.e. things you tried but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In python:
`yourString = float(yourString)`

In VBA:

```
yourString = CDbl(yourString)
```

if you're trying to convert "two" to the int 2 there is a good example here: [Is there a way to convert number words to Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers)