# How to split specific words in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

I have a university project. I want to split and convert words to numbers like five hundred three to 503.
I take string from text file but I don't how to split it.

The sentence I want to convert for test

```
there is five hundred three people
```

I want to split like this

```
there, is, five hundred three, people
```

and take in list to use dictionary to convert it to

```
there is 503 people
```

I searched so much site but I can't find anything about this. I tried *.split()* but it split every word and I can't use it for project.

Comment: Why don't you just perform a replace straight, with .replace('five hundred three', '503') on the string straight without the list intermediary

Comment: try this https://pypi.org/project/word2number/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to convert number words to Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers)

Comment: @ashiswin this is a test sentence there is so much words to replace not only five hundred three. for example five hundred five, sixty, eighty etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [`text2digits`](https://github.com/careless25/text2digits) package with:

```
pip install text2digits
```

Then use the package as follows to work with your example:

```
from text2digits import text2digits
t2d = text2digits.Text2Digits()
print t2d.convert("there is five hundred three people")
```

And the output is:

```
>>> 
there is 503 people
```

Comment: It didn't work in my way. It shows them like this. *there are 560-3 people.*

Comment: @Infeamous99, which Python version are you using?

Comment: You can try the code here https://repl.it/@cedriczg/text2digits . You need first to install the `text2digits` package first.

Comment: I am using python 3.8

Comment: Well, I tested the code I answered with `Python 2.7` and `Python 3.7` correctly. The first one locally on my machine and the second one in the http://repl.it online compiler

Comment: I found problem in text file. Your code is okay. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's python, so there is a library for this: https://github.com/careless25/text2digits

But, if you do not prefer using the library, this method (from the library) that does exactly what you want:

```
def text2int (textnum, numwords={}):
    if not numwords:
        units = [
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight",
        "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen",
        "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen",
        ]

        tens = ["", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]

        scales = ["hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion"]

        numwords["and"] = (1, 0)
        for idx, word in enumerate(units):  numwords[word] = (1, idx)
        for idx, word in enumerate(tens):       numwords[word] = (1, idx * 10)
        for idx, word in enumerate(scales): numwords[word] = (10 ** (idx * 3 or 2), 0)

    ordinal_words = {'first':1, 'second':2, 'third':3, 'fifth':5, 'eighth':8, 'ninth':9, 'twelfth':12}
    ordinal_endings = [('ieth', 'y'), ('th', '')]

    textnum = textnum.replace('-', ' ')

    current = result = 0
    curstring = ""
    onnumber = False
    for word in textnum.split():
        if word in ordinal_words:
            scale, increment = (1, ordinal_words[word])
            current = current * scale + increment
            if scale > 100:
                result += current
                current = 0
            onnumber = True
        else:
            for ending, replacement in ordinal_endings:
                if word.endswith(ending):
                    word = "%s%s" % (word[:-len(ending)], replacement)

            if word not in numwords:
                if onnumber:
                    curstring += repr(result + current) + " "
                curstring += word + " "
                result = current = 0
                onnumber = False
            else:
                scale, increment = numwords[word]

                current = current * scale + increment
                if scale > 100:
                    result += current
                    current = 0
                onnumber = True

    if onnumber:
        curstring += repr(result + current)

    return curstring
```

You can use it like this:

```
>>> text2int("I want fifty five hot dogs for two hundred dollars.")
 I want 55 hot dogs for 200 dollars.
```

Answer (score -1):

You would have to use a list of numbers written out and then search the string for all of them and replace them.

ie something like this

```
strings["one", "two", "three"...]      #list of numbers represented as strings
numbers[1, 2, 3...]                    #corrasponding numbers 

def replaceNumbers(string):            #function to replace numbers
    for x in range(len(strings)):      #loop through strings 
        #replace string with number
        string= string[:string.find(x)] + str(numbers[x]) + string[string.find(x) + len(x):] 
    return string
```

then you then need to figure out how to deal with hundreds, thousands, ect

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.