# how to efficiently convert words to integers in python to use in a calculation

Tags: python

A math challenge for class asks us to take words (like five seven six three) and change that to an integer (like 5763) to use in a calculation within the program.  There are several examples of words2number that take words that spell out a number (like five hundred and sixty five, as if you're writing a check).  But I want to take the individual words and place them into their corresponding number.

nine nine five zero = 9950, 
six three five = 635, 
etc.

Comment: I have the dict, but I cannot figure out the logic.  when I get the words, how to i iterate the dict and get the numbers out and put them into a single int?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers Answers given here satisfy your examples, but they don't look "as if you're writing a check"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to convert number words to Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
w_to_n = {'zero':'0', 'one':'1', 'two':'2', 'three':'3', 'four':'4',
     'five':'5', 'six':'6', 'seven':'7', 'eight':'8', 'nine':'9'
}

words ='nine nine five zero'
number = str()
for word in words.split():
    number += w_to_n[word]
int(number)
```

number:

```
 9950
```