# pyttsx3 string to numeric values

Tags: python, windows, pyttsx3

so I am trying to convert a spoken alphanumeric string into useable variable. example is a spoken ip address.
As an example:

```
string(one nine two period one six eight period zero period one slash twenty four)
```

turn this into

```
192.168.000.001/24
```

I understand some string formatting but this is beyond my knowledge.  I figure I could turn it into a dictionary. Use a variable and compare the alphanumeric against the numeric value. I am trying to do this without the google services, as it does phone numbers and addresses, but not something like an IP address.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert number words to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers) Refer to answer given by recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I TAKE NO CREDIT OF THIS ANSWER. FULL CREDITS GOES TO [recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44743/recursive) WHO PROVIDED THIS BEAUTIFUL ANSWER IN THIS** [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers).

```
def text2int(textnum, numwords={}):
if not numwords:
  units = [
    "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight",
    "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen",
    "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen",
  ]

  tens = ["", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]

  scales = ["hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion"]

  numwords["and"] = (1, 0)
  for idx, word in enumerate(units):    numwords[word] = (1, idx)
  for idx, word in enumerate(tens):     numwords[word] = (1, idx * 10)
  for idx, word in enumerate(scales):   numwords[word] = (10 ** (idx * 3 or 2), 0)

current = result = 0
for word in textnum.split():
    if word not in numwords:
      raise Exception("Illegal word: " + word)

    scale, increment = numwords[word]
    current = current * scale + increment
    if scale > 100:
        result += current
        current = 0

return result + current

 print text2int("seven billion one hundred million thirty one thousand three hundred thirty seven")
 #7100031337
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you need to turn a string of spelled-out characters (delineated by whitespace) into a string of the characters themselves. If so, I think this should do the trick:

```
def convert_spelled_chars(string:str, mapping:dict):
    # split at whitespace
    tokens = string.split()
    # map to values
    chars = [str(mapping[t]) for t in tokens]
    # join into one string again
    result = "".join(chars)
    return result
```

This takes in the string, and returns a string form of the IP address (I'm assuming you want it as a string?). Then it can be used in the following way:

```
mapping = {
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    "slash": "/"
}

print(convert_spelled_chars("one two slash two one", mapping))
#> "12/21"
```

It assumes that you know all of the possible spoken characters that can appear, which seems like a reasonable assumption if you're only using it for IP addresses.