# how can I convert a string like twenty two to a number in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example, I get a string like "twenty two plus three", then I split the string into a list ["twenty two", "plus", "three"] and I want to get the first and last elements of the list as a number. How?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Comment: Write a dictionary converting one-twenty to 1:20 (or use a list by index). Then write thirty, forty conversions to 30,40 etc. and figure out the logic for 31 etc.

Comment: @davetherock this cannot answer his question, because it's about converting plain numbers with quotes around, but this question is about converting number words to numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to convert number words to Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers)

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library word2number
Link: https://pypi.org/project/word2number/

After installing it,

```
from word2number import w2n
print(w2n.word_to_num('twenty two'))
```

Output:

```
22
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dict like this :
dico_units = {'one':1, 'two':2 ...}
dico_tens = {'ten':10, ...}
caution to 11, 12, 13
then check wich number fits :)