# Python - Converting strin to Int for comarison within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm taking an online class and there are assignments. The on i'm working now has me comparing 3 numbers together to look for a match. Works fine with int's but when I pass a "two" into the function instead of a 2, i'm not able to compare and if I try to convert it, i'm not able to either.

Any ideas?

```
boolHomework = homework3Bonus(1,2,"two")

def homework3Bonus(a,b,c):
    print("The type of input is", type(c))
    strA = a
    strB = b
    strC = int(c)  #this isn't working
    print("The type of input is", type(a))
    print("The strings are",strA,strB,strC)
    if (strA == strB) or (strB == strC) or (strA == strC):
        print("Match")
```

This gives the error
strC = int(c)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'two'

Comment: Welcome to SO.   ```int("two")``` doesn't work because ```two``` isn't a representation of a value integer.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out how to convert it...

Comment: i thought

strC = int(c) would take whatever is in C (say "two" in this example) and convert to an int?

How could I compare a number and a string then?

Comment: Yes,  but "two" isn't the same as "2".   It's a string that (for lack of a better phrase) represents the integer 2 in English.

Comment: Yep. You clearly showed me the issue.   That is why I tried to use the int(c) to convert it..   This was the challenge "bonus" in my online class.  I've tried many ways to figure it out. None of them working.

Basically the want me to compare 1,2,"two" and see if the are equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a functional way to do it, which also looks for words up to 10, this solution will work.

It allows for int values `5` ints as a string `'5'` or word representations `'five'` to be compared.

We apply map to all the incoming values to convert them to int where possible.

Then map a lambda over each combination of pairs in the list which compares and returns `True` or `False` for each combination. `itertools` is a python standard library.

`any` then checks if any value in our resulting list is `True`

```
import itertools

NUMBER_MAP = {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4,
    'five': 5,
    'six': 6,
    'seven': 7,
    'eight': 8,
    'nine': 9,
    'ten': 10
}


def to_int(val):
    if isinstance(val, str):
        try:
            # convert number in string to int, e.g '2', '5', etc
            val = int(val)
        except ValueError:
            # convert work representation to int
            val = NUMBER_MAP.get(val.lower(), val)
    return val


def homework3Bonus(a, b, c):

    if any(map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], itertools.combinations(map(to_int, (a, b, c)), 2))):
        print('Match')


homework3Bonus(3, 2, 'three')
homework3Bonus(3, 2, '3')
homework3Bonus(3, 2, 'two')
```

This could then easily be extended to take any number of arguments to find a match in an abitrary length of values.

```
def homework3Bonus(*args):

    if any(map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], itertools.combinations(map(to_int, args), 2))):
        print('Match')


homework3Bonus(3, 2, 1, 5, '6', 'three')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this **if you have low contraints** for which it is possible to write a list `stralpha` manually as given below:

```
def homework3Bonus(a,b,c):
    a, b, c = str(a), str(b), str(c)
    lst = [a, b, c]
    
    max_possible = 10
    strnum = [str(i) for i in range(max_possible)]
    stralpha = ["zero", "one", "two", three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]
    
    for i in range(3):
        if lst[i].isalpha():
            lst[i] = strnum[stralpha.index[lst[i].lower()]]

    return len(set(lst)) == 1
            

boolHomework = homework3Bonus(1, 2, "two")        # False
boolHomework = homework3Bonus("2", 2, "two")      # True
```

**If you have higher contraints**, you should refer to this: [Is there a way to convert number words to Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers)

Comment: OP wants to compare the string `one`, `two` etc with a literal number.

Comment: I really don't think that's what the homework is. He might have mis-conceptualized the question based on the trick case (1, "one", "1"), which should be False, as the question is **compare three integers**.

Comment: Thank you both for your reply. Indeed I am suppose to compare a 2 with a "two" and see if they match..

Here is the assignment

Extra Credit:

Modify your function so that strings can be compared to integers if they are equivalent. For example, if the following values are passed to your function:

6,5,"5"

You should modify it so that it returns true instead of false.

Hint: there's a built in Python function called "int" that will help you convert strings to Integers.

Comment: what are the constraints of the input? I mean are the values less than 10 only? Or it could be any large?

Comment: EDITED the anwer now.