# How to extract numbers of different forms from text

Tags: python, nlp

For example, given the text - "home price went up from 500 thousands to two millions". Is there an easy way, in Python, to get the two numbers -  500,000 and 2,000,000?

Comment: Search for NER within NLP

Comment: Please share a sample code of your question

Comment: Look into [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this can be to extract all the numbers and the immediate words next to them so e.g. [500, thousands] or [1.5, millions]. You can do this with a regex. Next, you convert the second string to its numerical value and multiply it with the first number to get the full numerical equivalent. You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers) answer for some ways to do that.