# Convert String into digit in SQL

Tags: sql

How to convert any string into digit in SQL without CASE and Decode function.
eg. THREE to 3
    FOUR to 4 
    FIVE to 5
    SIX to 6
  Range is not decided.. can be vary upto N.

Comment: Why do you want to do this without `CASE`?  What database are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why the limitation on not using `CASE`? Are we bothered about double digits or are we just decoding each one separately i.e. what would you want **12** to display?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189195/convert-string-ten-to-integer-10

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure whether this is what you need, but what about defining a table, say `digits`, like this:

```
digit: text | value: int
------------+-----------
one         | 1
two         | 2
three       | 3
           etc.
```

Then use a query, for example, like this one:

```
SELECT value FROM digits WHERE digit = 'FIVE'
```

Sure, it's pretty weird (to say the least), but nonetheless the use of `CASE` is avoided.