# dictionary list cocatenation from multiple user input while true

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am totally new to python. I am trying to do a dictionary concatenation from user input and print the result. I have searched the internet for all solutions, but no solutions. Please, help.

```
shoeCat = {1: 'Adidas', 2: 'Alexander McQueen', 3: 'Converse', 4: 'Fila', 5: 'Kids/Teens', 6: 'Men’s Kicks', 7: 'New Balance', 8: 'Nike', 9: 'OFF-White', 10: 'Puma', 11: 'Select Brands', 12: 'Slides', 13: 'Under Armour', 14: 'Women’s Kicks'}
mycat1 = input("Enter 1st category: ")
cat1 = [shoeCat[int(x)] for x in mycat1.split()]
print(cat1)
mycat2 = input("Enter 2nd Category: ")
cat2 = [shoeCat[int(x)] for x in mycat2.split()]
print(cat2)
final= cat1 + cat2
print(*final, sep = " | ")
```

How do i make the code to ask for infinite multiple user inputs whith the whiile true if statement.

```
while True:
print ('Enter Category: (Press enter to generate.)')
mycat1 = input("")
if mycat1 == '':
    break
```

I want to achieve these:

```
Enter 1st category: 1
['Adidas']
Enter 2nd Category: 2
['Alexander McQueen']
Enter 3rd Category: 6
['Men’s Kicks']
Enter 4th Category: 11
['Select Brands']
Enter 2nd Category: 13
['Under Armour']
Adidas | Alexander McQueen | Men’s Kicks | Select Brands | Under Armour
```

Please how do i make python3 get these result for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a list to store the values that you have printed:

```
shoeCat = {1: 'Adidas', 2: 'Alexander McQueen', 3: 'Converse', 4: 'Fila', 5: 'Kids/Teens', 6: 'Men’s Kicks', 7: 'New Balance', 8: 'Nike', 9: 'OFF-White', 10: 'Puma', 11: 'Select Brands', 12: 'Slides', 13: 'Under Armour', 14: 'Women’s Kicks'}
lst = []
while True:
    mycat1 = input("Enter Category: (Press enter to generate.)")
    if mycat1 == '':
        break
    lst.append(shoeCat[int(mycat1)])
    print(shoeCat[int(mycat1)])
print(*lst, sep=" | ")
```

`lst` stores the values that you have printed out. You can then just plainly print out the list with the required separator.

Note that this assumes the user always enters a valid integer input that is in `shoeCat`. Additional checks need to be in place to make sure it handles edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can append the user input to the same list every time. The while loop would accept input, if it's an empty string then break and print the list. Otherwise add the input to the list and print the value. The trickiest thing in your question is actually getting the ordinal number representation (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc), which there is an answer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647202/ordinal-numbers-replacement).

```
shoeCat = {1: 'Adidas', 2: 'Alexander McQueen', 3: 'Converse', 4: 'Fila', 5: 'Kids/Teens', 6: 'Men’s Kicks', 7: 'New Balance', 8: 'Nike', 9: 'OFF-White', 10: 'Puma', 11: 'Select Brands', 12: 'Slides', 13: 'Under Armour', 14: 'Women’s Kicks'}
ordinal = lambda n: "%d%s" % (n, "tsnrhtdd"[(n // 10 % 10 != 1) * (n % 10 < 4) * n % 10::4])
i = 1
final = []
while True:
    mycat1 = input(f"Enter {ordinal(i)} category: ")
    if mycat1:
        final.append(shoeCat[int(mycat1)])
        print(final[-1:])
        i += 1
    else:
        print(' | '.join(final))
        break
```