# Replace each occurrence with a separate value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was seeking a pandas solution to the following problem

Dataframe

```
col1,col2
1,a
2,a
3,a
4,a
```

Desired output: Replace every instance of a in col2 with a different value

```
col1,col2
1,cat
2,elephant
3,monkey
4,tiger
```

I've tried the [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function, but that replace all occurrences of `a`

```
df = df['col2'].replace('a','cat')
```

But doing this results in

```
col1,col2
1,cat
2,cat
3,cat
4,cat
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647202/ordinal-numbers-replacement

Comment: I'm guessing ordinality may skew the ask, so I am revising the desired output

Comment: You need a dictionary to map 1, 2,3 to cat,elephant,monkey etc.., then you can use `series.map`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
replacing_values = ["cat", "elephant", "monkey", "tiger"]
a_indices = (df["col2"] == "a").index
df.loc[a_indices, "col2"] = replacing_values
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `addtional` key with `cumcount`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('col2').cumcount().add(1).astype(str).add(df.col2)
df['new'].replace({'1a':'cat'})
Out[375]: 
0    cat
1     2a
2     3a
3     4a
dtype: object
```