# How to change datetime.date to st,nd,rd,th when changing to string using strftime

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

```
ex1)
date1 = datetime.date(2021, 1, 26)
date2 ='Tuesday, January 26th, 2021'

ex2)
date1 = datetime.date(2021, 2, 21)
date2 = 'Sunday, February 21st, 2021'
```

I want to change `date1` to `date2`. What should I do?

I tried this, but it didn't work out that 1's digits are 1,2,3 like datetime.date(2021, 2, 21),datetime.date(2021, 2, 2),datetime.date(2021, 2, 23)

```
date1 = strftime('%A, %B %dth, %Y')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're looking for the [ordinal numeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_numeral). borrowing from [Ordinal numbers replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9647202/10197418), you can use

```
import datetime

def ordinal(n: int) -> str:
    """
    derive the ordinal numeral for a given number n
    """
    return f"{n:d}{'tsnrhtdd'[(n//10%10!=1)*(n%10<4)*n%10::4]}"

date1 = datetime.date(2021, 1, 26)

dayOrdinal = ordinal(date1.day)

date1_string = date1.strftime(f'%A, %B {dayOrdinal}, %Y')
# 'Tuesday, January 26th, 2021'
```