# How to get ordinal Numbers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried getting some help from stack and l can across this [Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20007730/14420816)

I would like to know how to convert this into dart and use it to get ordinal numbers

```
ordinal = lambda n: "%d%s" % (n,"tsnrhtdd"[(n//10%10!=1)*(n%10<4)*n%10::4])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a package for this using the native platform libraries.

https://pub.dev/packages/ordinal_formatter

```
final ordinalString = await OrdinalFormatter().format(2) ?? ''; 
// -> 2nd

final localisedOrdinalString = await OrdinalFormatter().format(2, 'en_US') ?? ''; 
// -> 2nd
```

Answer (score 15):

Try with this

```
void main() {
   for(int i =1; i<=100;i++){
     print("$i${ordinal(i)}");
   }
}
String ordinal(int number) {
    if(!(number >= 1 && number <= 100)) {//here you change the range
      throw Exception('Invalid number');
    }

    if(number >= 11 && number <= 13) {
      return 'th';
    }

    switch(number % 10) {
      case 1: return 'st';
      case 2: return 'nd';
      case 3: return 'rd';
      default: return 'th';
    }
}
```

output:
1st
2nd
3rd
4th
5th
6th
7th
8th
9th
10th
..................

Comment: Thank you for response it uses day of the month?.. is there a way to extend it. For example 111th or more.

Comment: you can change the value range in ordinal number `  if(!(number >= 1 && number <= 100)) `

Comment: Do you even need the range check? It should work regardless, right?

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 2):

Resuable version of accepted answer.

```
main() {
  print(toOrdinal(3)); 
  // -> 3rd
  print(ordinalGenerator(end: 1000));
  // -> [1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th,..., 1000th]
  print(ordinalGenerator(start: 7, end: 14));
  // -> [7th, 8th, 9th, 10th, 11st, 12nd, 13rd, 14th]
}

List ordinalGenerator({int start = 1,required int end}) {
  if (start < 1) throw Exception('Start Number Can\' be less than 1');
  if (start > end) throw Exception('Invalid Range');

  return List.generate(
    end - (start == 1 ? 0 : start - 1),
    (index) => toOrdinal(index + start),
  );
}

String toOrdinal(int number) {
  if (number < 0) throw Exception('Invalid Number');

  switch (number % 10) {
    case 1:
      return '${number}st';
    case 2:
      return '${number}nd';
    case 3:
      return '${number}rd';
    default:
      return '${number}th';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using extensions, the code below can be used with any int type.
Since ordinals are based on the last figure of a digit; this int extension takes the integer value and converts it to string
Next, it gets the last index of said string and uses that to determine the ordinal.

```
extension NumberParsing on int {
  String toOrdinalString() {
    if ((this < 0)) {
      //here you change the range
      throw Exception('Invalid number: Number must be a positive number');
    }
    if (this == 0) {
      return '0';
    }

    String stringValue = toString();

    switch (stringValue[stringValue.length - 1]) {
      case '1':
        return stringValue + 'st';
      case '2':
        return stringValue + 'nd';
      case '3':
        return stringValue + 'rd';
      default:
        return stringValue + 'th';
    }
  }
}

// Usage:
int someIntValue = 25;
someIntValue.toOrdinalString();

//Output:
25th

// Generate Ordinals from 1 to 100
for(int i =1; i<=100;i++){
     print(i.toOrdinalString());
   }
```

Comment: This code appears to be correct, however, it fails on the 13th number because the 13th is not 13rd.  It is also possible that more numbers will be broken.

Comment: I have used numbers from 0 to 31 so I have found a solution for number 13.

    if (this == 13) {
      return '${stringValue}th';
    }