# is there any easier way to put word after numbers in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Hi I want to give text to code and code change every **Cardinal** numbers to **Ordinal** numbers in python

```
Input :
str = 'I was born in September 22 and I am 1 in swimming'
```

and I want to change it to :

```
I was born in September 22th and I am 1st in swimming
```

How can I do that in easiest way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordinal numbers replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647202/ordinal-numbers-replacement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function to make ordinals, e.g. this one taken from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647202/ordinal-numbers-replacement#answer-50992575):

```
def make_ordinal(match):
    n = match.group(0)
    n = int(n)
    suffix = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th'][min(n % 10, 4)]
    if 11 <= (n % 100) <= 13:
        suffix = 'th'
    return str(n) + suffix
```

and use regular expressions to do the replacement, using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

s = "I was born in September 22 and I am 1 in swimming"

re.sub(r"\d+", make_ordinal, s)
# 'I was born in September 22nd and I am 1st in swimming'
```