# for loop to add new columns based on previous calculations and to stop adding columns when entire index is nan

Tags: pandas, numpy, for-loop

I have a df that looks a bit like this:

```
data = data = [['2021-09-01', 100], ['2021-10-01', 200], ['2021-11-01', 300],
           ['2021-12-01', 400], ['2022-01-01', 500], ['2022-02-01', 600],
           ['2022-03-01', 700], ['2022-04-01', 800], ['2022-05-01', 900],
           ['2022-06-01', 1000], ['2022-07-01', 1100], ['2022-08-01', 1200],
           ['2022-09-01', 1300], ['2022-10-01', 1400], ['2022-11-01', 1500],
           ['2022-12-01', 1600], ['2023-01-01', 1700], ['2023-02-01', 1800],
           ['2023-03-01', 1900], ['2023-04-01', 2000], ['2023-05-01', 2100],
           ['2023-06-01', 2200], ['2023-07-01', 2300], ['2023-08-01', 2400]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Month Year', 'Sales'])
```

I am trying to figure out the number of purchases across the monthly unit sales, which follows a certain purchase pattern. Currently to this I am shifting the dataset by the purchase pattern which is initial purchase, 3 month purchase and then 6 month purchase thereafter. To figure this out I am applying the following calculation:

```
factor = 0.9
df['Initial Purchase'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['Sales'] - df['Sales'].shift(3) * factor) , df['Sales'], (df['Sales'] - df['Sales'].shift(3)) * factor)
df['2nd Purchase'] = df['Initial Purchase'].shift(3) * factor
df['3rd Purchase'] = df['2nd Purchase'].shift(6) * factor
df['4th Purchase'] = df['3rd Purchase'].shift(6) * factor
df['5th Purchase'] = df['4th Purchase'].shift(6) * factor
df['6th Purchase'] = df['5th Purchase'].shift(6) * factor
```

Which gives me a df that looks like this:

| Month Year | Sales | Initial Purchase | 2nd Purchase | 3rd Purchase | 4th Purchase | 5th Purchase | 6th Purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/09/2021 | 100 | 100 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/10/2021 | 200 | 200 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/11/2021 | 300 | 300 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/12/2021 | 400 | 270 | 90 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/01/2022 | 500 | 270 | 180 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/02/2022 | 600 | 270 | 270 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/03/2022 | 700 | 270 | 243 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/04/2022 | 800 | 270 | 243 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/05/2022 | 900 | 270 | 243 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/06/2022 | 1000 | 270 | 243 | 81 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/07/2022 | 1100 | 270 | 243 | 162 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/08/2022 | 1200 | 270 | 243 | 243 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/09/2022 | 1300 | 270 | 243 | 218.7 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/10/2022 | 1400 | 270 | 243 | 218.7 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/11/2022 | 1500 | 270 | 243 | 218.7 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01/12/2022 | 1600 | 270 | 243 | 218.7 | 72.9 | NaN | NaN |
| 01/01/2023 | 1700 | 270 | 243 | 218.7 | 145.8 | NaN | NaN |
| 01/02/2023 | 1800 | 270 | 243 | 218.7 | 218.7 | NaN | NaN |
| 01/03/2023 | 1900 | 270 | 243 | 218.7 | 196.83 | NaN | NaN |
| 01/04/2023 | 2000 | 270 | 243 | 218.7 | 196.83 | NaN | NaN |
| 01/05/2023 | 2100 | 270 | 243 | 218.7 | 196.83 | NaN | NaN |
| 01/06/2023 | 2200 | 270 | 243 | 218.7 | 196.83 | 65.61 | NaN |
| 01/07/2023 | 2300 | 270 | 243 | 218.7 | 196.83 | 131.22 | NaN |
| 01/08/2023 | 2400 | 270 | 243 | 218.7 | 196.83 | 196.83 | NaN |

Does anyone know how I can achieve the same using a for loop? so I don't have to manually calculate each purchase, given that the initial purchase calculation is different and then the other calculations are contingent on the preceding calculation. Also to have it end when the entire column length in nan, as you can see the 6th purchase is nan and not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your main problem is in creating the column names and then assigning values to those names.  There are several paths you could go, but a straight forward for loop is below.

```
name_list = [str(num) + suffixes[num % 100] + " Purchase" for num in range(1, 20)]
name_list[0] = "Initial Purchase"

for counter, col_name in enumerate(name_list):
    if counter == 0:
        df[col_name] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['Sales'] - df['Sales'].shift(3) * factor) , df['Sales'], (df['Sales'] - df['Sales'].shift(3)) * factor)
    elif counter == 1:
        df[col_name] = df[name_list[counter - 1]].shift(3) * factor
    else:
        df[col_name] = df[name_list[counter - 1]].shift(6) * factor

    if df[col_name].isnull().all():
        df.pop(col_name)
        break
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9647336/1678467) for the ordinal number creation.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you so much!