# Extension for Double to accept String as initializer in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a way in Swift to define an extension for type Double to accept String as initializer? In a nutshell, just to figure out feasibility, I need this to work:

```
var double:Double = "one"
println(double) // Outputs "1.0"
```

I am guessing it should be made compliant to StringLiteralConvertible, but not sure about the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to natural-language-parse a string, and generate a floating-point number from it?

Well, the extension is the easy part.  Just create a failable initializer for it:

```
let digits = [
    "zero", "one", "two", "three",
    "four", "five", "six", "seven",
    "eight", "nine",
]

extension Double {
    init?(fromEnglishString s: String) {
        if let digit = find(digits, s) {
            self.init(Double(digit))
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

let d = Double(fromEnglishString: "one")
// d is {Some 1.0}
```

The hard part is going to be finding a good parser for all the ways you can express numbers in English (*especially* floating-point numbers).  That's much more tricky.  You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70161/how-to-read-values-from-numbers-written-as-words) more language-agnostic answer interesting.

You could also write a `StringLiteralConvertible` extension for it.  However, this is only for when you are initializing your value directly from a string literal at compile time – which would be a bit pointless, I mean, do you really need word-based number literals in your source code?  The other problem is literal convertible initializers can't be failable, so you'll be stuck with returning a default value (maybe `NaN`?) if the string can't be parsed.

Nevertheless, if you really want one:

```
extension Double: StringLiteralConvertible {
    public typealias StringLiteralType = String
    public typealias UnicodeScalarLiteralType = String
    public typealias ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType = String

    public init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: UnicodeScalarLiteralType) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: value)
    }

    public init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: value)
    }

    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        if let d = Double(fromEnglishString: value) {
            self = d
        } else {
            self = 0.0
        }
    }
}

let doubleFromLiteral: Double = "three"
// doubleFromLiteral is {Some 3.0}
```

Comment: Nice solution. up voted. I think I will delete my pour answer. kkkk

Comment: yours is fine :) just depends whether you consider it something you should initiate the source type (like `String.toInt`) or the destination type (like `Double.init(_ other: Float80)` or `init?(rawValue: RawValue)` for Enums)...

Comment: StringLiteralConvertible extension example is great! Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do exactly what your code example does... Write an extension that implements the `StringLiteralConvertible` protocol. There's a decent write up on the literal convertibles [at NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/).

It'd probably look something like this:

```
extension Double: StringLiteralConvertible {
    convenience init(value: String) {
        if value == "one" {
            self = 1.0
        /*
        Add more English-to-number conversion magic here
        */
        } else {
            return NaN
        }
    }
}
```

There's a bit more to it than that — `StringLiteralConvertible` extends a couple of other protocols whose requirements you have to meet, and then there's the whole business of translating English to numbers. You may have a feasibility problem there, but making `Double`s from strings is technically possible.

On top of all that, there are more questions as to whether this is a good idea.

- Literal initializers can't fail, so you have to return a sentinel value for strings you can't parse a number from. Not very swifty.
- Do you actually want to convert string *literals*, or strings passed in at runtime? The former doesn't seem super useful. The latter requires different syntax at the call site, but lets you make clear that you're defining/using a conversion function.

Comment: This won't work.  `StringLiteralConvertible` requires an `init` not an `init?`.  Also, if you wanted to create doubles from strings at runtime (i.e. not from literals but from say user input) you shouldn't use `StringLiteralConvertible`.

Comment: That's what I get for answering from memory on the phone. :-/ Must've been confusing literal initializers with enum initializers... Edit forthcoming.