# Converting Number in String form to integer in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I convert a string that spells a number (for example "four") to an integer ? In summary I'm trying to change "four" to 4. The range of numbers I need to convert are from 1 - 99. numbers over nine will have a dash (example: twenty-five).

What I have tried, string->number, but this returns false. I'm not sure what else to try.

Please help.

Comment: all i could think of was string->number "four"

Comment: i can't think of another way to do it other then defining 99 terms

Comment: It is not as simple as that here is a good answer in python that perhaps you could convert to scheme http://stackoverflow.com/a/493788/6328256 and here is a question that goes over the general algorithm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70161/how-to-read-values-from-numbers-written-as-words

Comment: i'll give it a try but I just started using this programming language and am not very familiar with lists.

Comment: I haven't had much luck yet but I'm going to keep trying if anyone else has a idea please let me know thanks.

Comment: string->number converts a string that is similar to a number like "1234" to type integer 1234. it can not convert a string like four to integer 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of converting a number from its string form to integer form:

```
(define (string->num string)
  (define dict '(("one" 1) ("two" 2) ("three" 3) ("four" 4) ("five" 5)
                 ("six" 6) ("seven" 7) ("eight" 8) ("nine" 9) ("ten" 10)
                 ("eleven" 11) ("twelve" 12) ("thirteen" 13) ("fourteen" 14)
                 ("fifteen" 15) ("sixteen" 16) ("seventeen" 17) ("eighteen" 18)
                 ("ninteen" 19) ("twenty" 20) ("thirty" 30) ("forty" 40)
                 ("fifty" 50) ("sixty" 60) ("seventy" 70) ("eighty" 80)
                 ("ninety" 90)))
  (define (get-num str lst)
    (cond [(empty? lst) 0]
          [(equal? str (first (first lst)))
           (second (first lst))]
          [else (get-num str (rest lst))]))
  (define str-lst (regexp-split #rx"-" string))
  (define len (length str-lst))
  (define base (get-num (first str-lst) dict))
  (cond [(equal? len 1)
         base]
        [(equal? len 2)
         (+ base (get-num (second str-lst) dict))]))
```

Function uses regexp splitting to separate the string into two non-hyphenated parts, eg. `(regexp-split #rx"-" "twenty-four")` returns `'("twenty" "four")`, and `(regexp-split #rx"-" "one")` returns `'("one")`. The idea is to use the dictionary (list-of lists) as a source, and look up the value of the string, if a single string, or look up values of both strings, if there were a hyphen. If there are two strings, their values are added, eg. from `'("twenty" "four")`, values of both "twenty" and "four" are looked up, after which they are added to return 24 (20 + 4).

Comment: Hey thanks for the help I also figured out a similar way of doing it but instead of using a list I defined the same set of numbers you did and I also used (con to set the numbers there equal to. Then I switch the string im trying to covert to a number to a symbol and use equal? To compare and if there the same I call the number Ito equal to. But your way is definitely a lot more quick and easier:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting solution:

```
(define count
  (lambda (limit)
    (let loop ((i 0))
      (let ((number (format #f "~r" i)))
        (if (equal? number limit)
            i
            (loop (+ i 1)))))))
```

Comment: That looks more like a Common Lisp `format` than a Scheme or Racket `format`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Oops, you're right. I did not notice the Racket tag. Should I delete my answer?