# In Node/Javascript, how do I map cardinality from string to int?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

For example, I have user input any string: "1st", "2nd", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "9999th", etc.  These are just examples, the user can input any string.

I want to map this to integer cardinality:

```
"1st" -> 0
"2nd" -> 1
"third" -> 2
"fourth" -> 3
"fifth" -> 4
"9999th" -> 9998
```

So I need some kind of function where:

```
   function mapCardinality(input: string): number{
     let numberResult:number = ??
     return numberREesult;
   }
```

and I can call it like this:

```
console.log(
  mapCardinality("1st"), // print 0
  mapCardinality("2nd"), // print 1
  mapCardinality("third"), // print 2
  mapCardinality("fourth"), // print 3
  mapCardinality("fifth"), // print 4
  mapCardinality("9999th") // print 9998
);
```

Comment: With an associative array?

Comment: Where am I going to get the mapping?

Comment: what does happen with `2`?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, fixed!

Comment: How do you get that _string as input_? For converting it into corresponding integers you can use an object: `{ "1st": 0, "2nd": 1, ... }`

Comment: User input, one at a time.  I will clarify my example.

Comment: I can't JUST map them, the examples are just examples, what if the user input 99th?  I can't just sit there and map every integer in the universe.

Comment: That's why I asked how you get the input.

Comment: By user input, which can be anything they want

Comment: Why is it 1st, 2nd, third .. why not 1st, 2nd, 3rd or first, second, third .. shouldn't you just stick with one?

Comment: Related: [How to read values from numbers written as words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70161/how-to-read-values-from-numbers-written-as-words)

Answer (score 0):

Just look it up in an array or parse it as number:

```
const mapCardinality = c => {
   const pos = ["1st", "2nd", "third", "fourth",  "fifth"].indexOf(c);
   return pos === -1 ? parseInt(c, 10) - 1 : pos;
};
```

Comment: That definitely wold not work, as these are just example, what if the user wrote 999th?  I can't write a map for every cardinality in the universe.

Comment: @bill and what if he wrote "ninehundredninetynineth" ?

Comment: I am just going to tell the user that I didn't understand that one

Comment: @bill then why couldn't you just tell the user to input the `_ _ _ th` with numbers? That would make everyones lifes easier

Comment: i was hoping there is already a library in npm that I could use.  I would do regex if no existing solution exist.

Comment: @Bill note that asking for library recommendations is off-topic for SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Answer (score 0):

I'd first ask what are the suffixes for all of the inputs?

- 'nd', 'rd', 'st', 'th' (most numbers)

If they enter an integer with the above prefixes then you could write the following function:

```
const getInteger = input => input.slice(0, -2);
const num = getInteger('999th');
console.log(num); // prints "999"
```

If they enter the elongated variant, it becomes much more complex, especially when it comes to typos, lack of spaces, etc. One way could be to map single digit words ('one', 'two', etc), tens ('ten', 'twenty', etc'), hundreds, thousands, and so on instead of every number imaginable.  I would then parse and find matching words to give a result. That being said it is still limiting. I would strongly suggest limiting user input formats. Why can't the user input an integer?

```
const cardinalDictionary = {
  'zero': 0,
  'one': 1,
  ...,
  'twenty',
  ...,
  'hundred': 100,
  'thousand': 1000,
};
```