# The users keep saying things like 'twelve thirty four' instead of 'one two three four'

Tags: groovy, nlp

Users never just say "one two three four", they say "twelve thirty four" and things like that. I have a very complicated story about ABNF grammars and ASR engines but I'll just ask simply:

How can I generate a list of all the different ways someone might say '1234'? The number can be any number of digits.

I've seen numerous examples on how to expand a number in a [grammatically correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70161/how-to-read-values-from-numbers-written-as-words?rq=1), but my users never use proper grammar. "10217" becomes "ten two seventeen". "78749" becomes "seventy eight seven fourty nine".

Comment: And what is your question now?

Comment: I had a ton of extraneous information here that I've parred down about WHY I was doing this. Hopefully my question is more concise and clear now.

Comment: Check if the next word can still be a number when combined, e.g. 10-2 doesn't make sense as 12, because there is twelve. On the other hand, 30-4 can be 34. And then consistently use the shortest number you can find, maybe even store the separators (where you split) so you can rediscover what has been said.